# mkfs.ntfs: Maximum label length

Tags: 20.04, ntfs

man 8 of mkfs.ntfs does not inform you of the maximum length of a label. Which?

Answer (score 0):

https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfslabel
This has solved my problem. Max is 128 chars.
I have tested this for myself with mkfs.ntfs and I have verified that it is true but the 64th character is not recognized, so I have set the reasonable truncation to 63 characters within my script.